# Replace the text in pdf using python without changing the pdf structure

Tags: python, pypdf

Each pdf has different encoded formats, Able to replace some pdf's. But some are not. What is the reason behind this? I am stuck at this point

**Ex:1**

> Tm 0 g [(Amount In)1( Words: )] TJ /FAAABC 8 Tf [(Three Lakh)-1( S)1(e)-1(ven Thousand)-1( S)1(e)-1(ven Hund)-1(red Ninety Two Rup)-1(ees And Two Paise Only)] TJ ET Q Q Q q 1 0 0 1 0 442.59799194 cm q 1 g 0.125 0.25 m 560.02502441 0.25 l 560.02502441 8.25 l 0.125 8.25 l h f* Q q 0.125 0.25 m 560.02502441 0.25 l 560.02502441 8.25 l 0.125 8.25 l h W n q 1 0 0 1 0.125 0.25 cm Q Q Q q 1 0 0 1 0 450.84799194 cm q 1 g 0.125 0.25 m 560.02502441 0.25 l 560.02502441 9.75 l 0.125 9.75 l h f* Q q 0.125 0.25 m 560.02502441 0.25 l 560.02502441 9.75 l 0.125 9.75 l h W n q 1 0 0 1 5.625 0.25 cm BT /FAAAAJ 8 Tf 1 0 0 -1 0 6.8499999

**Ex:2**

> ' 8 Tf', '(  :Two Thousand Eight Hundred Eighty Three Only)Tj', '1 0 0 1 34.85 237.161 Tm', '/F2',

After running the python script, These are the examples.

- Ex:1 - I'm unable to replace the text and
- Ex:2 - able to replace the text

Can anyone suggest what is ex:1 format and how to replace that text?

```py
def replace_text(content, replacements = dict()):
    lines = content.splitlines()
    result = ""
    in_text = False

    for line in lines:
        if line == "BT":
            in_text = True
    
        elif line == "ET":
            in_text = False
    
        elif in_text:
            cmd = line[-2:]
            if cmd.lower() == 'tj':
                replaced_line = line
                for k, v in replacements.items():
                    replaced_line = replaced_line.replace(k, v)
                result += replaced_line + "\n"
            else:
                result += line + "\n"
            continue
    
        result += line + "\n"
    
    return result

def process_data(object, replacements):
    data = object.getData()
    decoded_data = data.decode('utf-8')
    replaced_data = replace_text(decoded_data, replacements)
    encoded_data = replaced_data.encode('utf-8')
    if object.decodedSelf is not None:
        object.decodedSelf.setData(encoded_data)
    else:
        object.setData(encoded_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True, help="path to PDF document")  #Canon Rental
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    in_file = args\["input"\]
    filename_base = in_file.replace(os.path.splitext(in_file)\[1\], "")
    replacements = {'02-JUN-21': '03 June 2022', '16 November 2022': '03 June 2022'}
    
    pdf = PdfFileReader(in_file)
    writer = PdfFileWriter()
    for page_number in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
    
        page = pdf.getPage(page_number)
        contents = page.getContents()
        if isinstance(contents, DecodedStreamObject) or isinstance(contents, EncodedStreamObject):
            process_data(contents, replacements)
        elif len(contents) > 0:
            for obj in contents:
                if isinstance(obj, DecodedStreamObject) or isinstance(obj, EncodedStreamObject):
                    streamObj = obj.getObject()
                    process_data(streamObj, replacements)
        page[NameObject("/Contents")] = contents.decodedSelf
        writer.addPage(page)
    
         with open(filename_base + f"_result_{i}.pdf", 'wb') as out_file:
            writer.write(out_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. My problem here is, I can able to replace the text in second Example, but I couldn't replace in first example. Could you please help me out of that replacing. Like difference of Encoding in both the examples

Comment: Yeah, But, I can't replace/edit this `(Amount In)1( Words: )` because we don't know the format of this, until unless, we decode. By looking at, we can see only `(Amount In Words: )`. As far of my knowledge some pdf's are encoded with Non-Standard encoding technique. Due to that we can't edit in a programmatically way. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Your question doesn't even specify what you're trying to replace -- and of course it can be guessed from your code. But please be specific with your questions.

Comment: Hi KJ & James, Thanks for responding. Just for an example, I wanna replace something like amount (Two Thousand Eight Hundred Eighty Three Only) from Two Thousand to Nine Thousand (More Specific Two is replaced with Nine) That's it.
I even tried with decompression techniques as well but ends with the same result.
Note: Couldn't change any alignment (Structure of PDF) like ups and downs of whole string after replacing.